# Generate random number based on a certain pattern and able to test against the pattern

Tags: random, pattern-recognition

I have very little idea about random numbers and patterns, so I am not sure whether this is actually possible or not.

I want to generate random numbers, that will follow a fixed pattern (perhaps this itself breaks the definition of 'randomness'?). Say for example, a number whose every alternate digit will be even/odd, like 123456. For such a pattern, say of 30 digits, I want to generate random numbers. And when generated, I want to verify the number against the pattern (so here I will verify whether the random number generated has every alternate digit as odd/even, if so, then it succeeds the check)

Is there any way to develop a fairly complicated (and if I may, notoriously difficult to find out by anybody else) pattern and generate random numbers in that pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is much more with defining a pattern you like than with the random numbers.  Taking your alternate even/odd example, each digit has five choices, so you can just generate a random number from $0$ through $4$ for each digit.  If the digit is supposed to be an even one, double it. If the digit is supposed to be odd, double it and add $1$.  Now you have a number with digits alternating as desired that is randomly chosen among all the numbers that satisfy your criterion.

The problem you are seeing is that this is too easy a pattern for someone to identify.  Choosing an appropriately hard pattern is not really a mathematical problem.  You might just pick some ten digit prime number $p$ and have your pattern be multiples of that.  When you want a random number thirty digits long, generate a random between $0$ and $10^{30}/p$, multiply by $p$ and report the result.  Again your reported number will be random in the acceptable space.  Clearly there are many patterns that can be defined.

Comment: Okay, so suppose the the prime number I pick is `5915587277`. The pattern has to be a multiple of it, so suppose it is `12`, so the pattern becomes `5915587277*12 = 70987047324`. So I have to generate a random number between `0` and `10^30/70987047324`. A simple random.randint() between `0` and `10^30/70987047324` gives, for example, `7250449821803687962`. So how do I verify it now, that this is indeed a number following my pattern?

Comment: You didn't finish.  Now you multiply $7250449821803687962 \cdot 70987047324=514688024620665764396223113688$ which is your number.  You don't need to check because you constructed it correctly.  If you do want to check, you do $514688024620665764396223113688 \pmod  {70987047324}=0$  The mod operator is represented by the percent sign in many computer languages.  You don't need the factor $12$ here if you want more numbers to be acceptable.

Comment: Yep, right. Thanks!

Comment: Hey sorry, I just looked at it again, how come it is random? We first get `7250449821803687962`, which we then multiply with `70987047324`, to get a result. Which will of course be divisible by `70987047324`, since it is one of the multipliers. What is random in it?

Comment: "Random" can be used in many ways.  It looked to me that you were using it as "numbers that do not have an obvious pattern to somebody who doesn't know how they are created". $111111111111$ and $123123123123$ would fail this test, even if they were in fact the output of a random number generator.  The number I suggested (if you had lots in that class) would fail the tests of a computer random number, but it certainly "looks random".  You originally asked for numbers that fit some pattern.  Please clarify what you want.

Comment: Okay I will give my use case. The client will generate the random number and send it to server, server will verify it to see if it fits the pattern, in which case it will understand that the client is authorized. Here, if I send `514688024620665764396223113688`, it is of no use because the server has no idea about `70987047324`.

Comment: You need the server to know the rule you are checking, otherwise you can't check it.  Besides, user authentication is an area you shouldn't roll your own-read the stackexchange on security to see why.  There are validated software packages for that sort of thing.

Comment: I may not eventually roll it, I am just trying to find out whether I can. Doesn't hurt trying.. :)